# The best practices using ViewModel and Flow to communicate with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building an app with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. The goal of this app is to retrieve song records from a Firebase Realtime Database and then display them in MusicsScreen. Actually, the app is working correctly but, as a beginner, I am unsure if I am following the correct practices

My application consists of 3 screens/views that are accessible through the NavGraph. Here is the tree of my project :

[image: project's tree]

The part of the project where I would like some advice is when I create the `MusicsViewModel` and when I share data from the view model to the `MusicsScreen`. The followings are the `MusicsViewModel` and the `MusicsScreen` implementation.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.karaokeapp.data.Song
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

class MusicsViewModel(
    private val database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(URL_OF_MY_FIREBASE_DATABSE)
) : ViewModel() {

    var songs = flow {
        val resultDatabase = database.get().await()
        val myMusicsList = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Song>>()

        for(cat in resultDatabase.children) {
            myMusicsList[cat.key.toString()] = mutableListOf()
            for (song in cat.children) {
                myMusicsList[cat.key.toString()]?.add(
                    Song(
                        title = song.child("title").value.toString(),
                        author = song.child("author").value.toString()
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        emit(myMusicsList)
    }
}
```

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.karaokeapp.ui.theme.WitheMic
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.example.karaokeapp.components.ExpandableCard


@Composable
fun MusicsScreen(
    viewModel: MusicsViewModel = viewModel(),
    onGoHome : () -> Unit
) {
    val flowSongs by viewModel.songs.collectAsState(initial = mutableMapOf())


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .background(color = WitheMic)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ){
            IconButton( onClick = onGoHome){
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "return to Home"
                )
            }
        }
        if (flowSongs.isNotEmpty()) {
            ExpandableCard(flowSongs)
        }

    }
}
```

I have two questions :

(1): Is it ok to instantiate the viewModel like this (inside the composable function arguments)? If not, where should I put it?

(2): Is it a good idea to use a flow like I did to handle the upcoming data from Firebase?

Comment: I edited your question to remove the parts that make it off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions should not be open-ended or lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to get your view model as you did. That's how they do it in the Compose documentation. "Instantiate" is not exactly the right word though. It is only instantiated (under the hood of the `viewModel()` function) once, and only if that same ViewModel hasn't been instantiated elsewhere in the composition. After that, `viewModel()` returns the already-instantiated instance.

You can also put `val viewModel: MusicsViewModel = viewModel()` inside the body of your Composable if you choose. The reason it might be better to put it as a function argument is so you have the option to pass in a mocked version of your ViewModel in a unit test.

It doesn't really make conceptual sense to use a Flow when you are only emitting a single thing. Conceptually, it makes more sense to use a Deferred or a suspend function, to communicate only one item will arrive. This won't change your end result, but the code is clearer about intent and what is happening.

I also used Kotlin iterable operators for simplifying your code for generating the Map of Lists. You should not be returning mutable maps and lists to use as state, because that is error prone.

```
class MusicsViewModel(
    private val database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(URL_OF_MY_FIREBASE_DATABSE)
) : ViewModel() {

    suspend fun getSongs(): Map<String, List<Song>> {
        val resultDatabase = database.get().await()
        return resultDatabase.children.associate { cat ->
            val songList = cat.children.map { song ->
                Song(
                    title = song.child("title").value.toString(),
                    author = song.child("author").value.toString()
                )
            }
            cat.key.toString() to songList
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MusicsScreen(
    viewModel: MusicsViewModel = viewModel(),
    onGoHome : () -> Unit
) {
    val songs by produceState<Map<String, List<Song>>>(emptyMap(), viewModel) { value = viewModel.getSongs() }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I prefer your way to do, the map generation is a little more readable. So, your suspend function is returning all the pair ( key, value) of the map at once ? But the produceState line is throwing an error : " Not enough information to infer type variable T.
produceState calls should assign value inside the producer lambda.
Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable." I do not really understand this. Can you explain it ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed putting `value = `. I don't know from memory if you can omit the `<Map<String, List<Song>>>` from after `produceState`. If it's grayed out after you type `value =`, then you can omit it to be concise.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you cannot omit it. I think I'll read the doc about the functions you used in your code snippet to better understand them. I have nothing more to say, all is working fine now, thank you!